# Penetration depth of thermal IR into building and insulation materials

Tags: optics, infrared-radiation

What are the values of the penetration depth (or the attenuation coefficient) of thermal infrared radiation (say, 5-20 $\mu$m wavelength) into common building and insulation materials (brick, stone, glass, PMMA, rockwool, EPS/XPS, PIR, textiles)?

The emissivity values are easy to find, but these values apply to opaque thicknesses and I don't know what these thickness are for each of the materials. Obviously, metal foils are opaque at micrometer thickness and glass is opaque at 1/4 inch thickness, but that's about all the information about IR penetration depth that I've been able to find.

It is also possible to find the complex refractive index values for the constituents of these materials, but the penetration depth is often dominated by scattering instead of by intrinsic abosrption, i.e. by particle/grain/pore/defect size.

Motivation: I want to understand the magnitude of the contribution of radiative losses to total thermal losses of a building. Also, I want to understand the application of radiant thermal barriers for building insulation. For example, When non-opaque layers of insulation are used, radiative and conductive modes de-couple. I want to know when this happens. Building engineers seem to be largely oblivious to the issue of penetration depth, therefore I'm turning to the physics community for help.

Comment: It might help focus answers if you included your application: why do you want to know this?

Comment: I want to understand the magnitude of the contribution of radiative losses to total thermal losses of a building. Also, I want to understand the application of radiant thermal barriers for building insulation. For example, When non-opaque layers of insulation are used, radiative and conductive modes de-couple. I want to know when this happens. Building engineers seem to be largely oblivious to the issue of penetration depth, therefore I'm turning to the physics community for help.

Comment: Good information: add it to your question.